# Same hibernate session between JUnit tests causing problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4, dbunit

I'm developing a web app which is based in Spring 2.5 and hibernate 3. Recently I've introduced JUnit tests and I've done some integration tests using DBUnit framework. DBUnit is supposed to update the database with an xml dataset between one test and another, and it's working well, as I've seen.

However, when I update an element in a test, hibernate seems to catch this information and even I load the element in the following test, the information is the one I've modified. If I look the DB when the execution is paused, the Data Base is properly reseted by DBUnit. So I think it can be an Hibernate problem..

Is there a way to make a tearDown between tests saying I want a new hibernate session for my spring context? By the way, I'm not using Spring annotations and I get the Spring context by code:

```
String[] contextLocations = new String[2];
contextLocations[0] = "WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml";
contextLocations[1] = "src/System_V3/test/applicationContext.xml";
context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(contextLocations);
```

DBUnit setUp:

```
@Before
public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    handleSetUpOperation();
}

private static void handleSetUpOperation() throws Exception {
    conn = getConnection();
    conn.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
    final IDataSet data = getDataSet();
    try {
        DatabaseOperation.REFRESH.execute(conn, data);
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
}

private static IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException,
        DatabaseUnitException {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    return new DatabaseConnection(DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_database", "root", "pass"));
}

private static IDataSet getDataSet() throws IOException, DataSetException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = TestPrueba.class.getClassLoader();
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(classLoader
            .getResourceAsStream("System_V3/test/dataset.xml"));
}
```

Tests are done in JUnit 4 using only @Test annotations and test class is not extending any library class.

Any suggestion?

Comment: as you are annotating your setupBeforeClass method with `@Before`: are you aware of the difference between `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` JUnit4 annotations?

Comment: @Korgen, this setUpBeforeClass() method is calling DBUnit for inserting dataSet data into database, before each test is executed. Yes, I want this in that way.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is something that can help you - but just in case...

Try to use session.clear() and use it in teardown method.
Please take a look here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear()

According to spec session.clear() ->
Completely clear the session. Evict all loaded instances and cancel all pending saves, updates and deletions. Do not close open iterators or instances of ScrollableResults.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your tests within a transaction. This can be achieved by setting the [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) for your test. After this is configured you can use `@Transactional` annotation per test.

With this approach you can `@Autowired` your beans directly to your test too.

For instance:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context-file.xml" })
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    private void myFirstTest() {
        ...
        myService.executeSomething();
        ...
    }

}
```

and of course, you can set the default behaviour to RollBack on your test class annotating it with `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true/false)`